# Adding a string to the end of a pre-existing txt file

Tags: java, file, file-io

I did check out the other questions that had been about this. But the provided solutions seemed to not work for me. I have an input file made of hexadecimal characters. After reading the characters in as a String my program calculates a CRC-16 value for the file. After doing to I need to Append that CRC-16 value to the end of the file. How can can I do this simply.

For example) 
Input file reads: 45
CRC-16: 7464
The original file should be append to read: 457464

I'm am not that well versed in file i/o and I have been quite dependent on the Scanner and URL classes for getting paths and reading data.

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a FileWriter, with the true parameter at the end which causes us to append to the file.

```
try(BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("path"),true))){
  bf.write(text to append);
}
```

You may find this tutorial helps:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-append-content-to-file-in-java/

As suggested I've updated this to show try with resources, which means the writer will be correctly closed even if there is an exception.

Comment: Not a good example. You should be showing a try-with-resources example.